# Javascript how to put xml2js into a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml2js

I am trying to export a function which will parse a xml to json object.

```
export const parse = (body) => {
  const parser = new xml2js.Parser({explicitArray: false, trim: true});
  parser.parseString(body, (err, result) => {
    if (err) return err;
    parser.parseString(result['soapenv:Envelope']['soapenv:Body']['ns1:searchResponse'].searchReturn._, (err, result) => {
      if (err) return err;
      console.log(result);
      return result;
    });
  });
}
```

The problem I am having is that the function returns undefined, however, it manages to console.log the correct result.

Answer (score 3):

since your function is asynchronous you can convert it to promise.

```
export const parse = (body) => {

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  const parser = new xml2js.Parser({explicitArray: false, trim: true});
  parser.parseString(body, (err, result) => {
    if (err) return reject(err);
    parser.parseString(result['soapenv:Envelope']['soapenv:Body']['ns1:searchResponse'].searchReturn._, (err, result) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      resolve(result);
    });
  });
  }


})
```

You can use it this way..

```
const result = await parse(<somebody>)
```

Comment: I believe you mean `return resolve(result)`. But apart from that, it works.

Comment: Nope, you dont have to return it, `resolve` will return the value, i used `return` with `reject` so that function doesnt execute any further

Answer (score 2):

The parser is async, so you need to account for that using a callback or a promise.

```
const parser = new xml2js.Parser({explicitArray: false, trim: true});

export const parse = (body) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  parser.parseString(body, (err, result) => {
    if(err) return reject(err);

    return resolve(result);    
  });
});
```

Usage.

```
module.parse(xml).then((parsedResult) => {

});
```

Comment: Or as mentioned below for usage we can use `const result = await parse(<somebody>)`.